# Pyspark DataFrame actions dont work in VsCode Debug Mode

Tags: visual-studio-code, pyspark

Whenever i want to use a pyspark dataframe action (e.g. show()) in VSCode debug mode, the debugger seems to run into a Deadlock and doesnt do anything. If i run the program without debug mode, it works fine.

I found that some people had the same issue in this thread: 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65739467/pyspark-dataframe-methods-i-e-show-can-not-be-printed-in-vs-code-debug-cons

A workaround that has been posted there is to add the following line and press F5 in debug mode when its deadlocked:

`for x in range(100): time.sleep(1)`

Is there any real fix for that except using the solution that has been posted in the other thread?