# vscode python debugger really slow for pyspark

Tags: python, apache-spark, debugging, pyspark, vscode-debugger

I'm attempting to work with PySpark within some Docker containers, utilizing a remote interpreter to execute PySpark code inside the container through the development containers extension. Additionally, I'd like to utilize the Python debugger.

However, when I execute certain DataFrame operations like head, collect, etc. (which appears to be the case for almost all DataFrame operations), the execution of these commands is extremely slow and takes a long time to complete. Sometimes, it even causes the debugger to crash.

I have seen similar questions, such as [pyspark dataframe methods (i.e. show()) can not be printed in vs code debug console](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65739467/pyspark-dataframe-methods-i-e-show-can-not-be-printed-in-vs-code-debug-cons), where there doesn't seem to be a real solution to the problem.

Therefore, I am looking to find out if anyone has discovered a new solution to this issue up to now.